# Installing Ubuntu 16 on USB

Tags: usb-drive

I was following a tutorial on installing Ubuntu on a usb but encountered a problem. It said to find the usb stick labelled as /dev/sdb but there is none. It is all /dev/sda 
The usb stick is a 16gb Transcend. Back of the usb package says it is compatible with mac and Windows, not sure if that matters.

[http://imgur.com/a/ni4hE](https://imgur.com/a/ni4hE)

Comment: Are you by any chance trying to install to the same USB you're booting the live session from? It can't be done.

Comment: @MichaelBay I suppose. After using Rufus to transfer the iso to my usb, I restarted my computer and booted from my usb. It gave me three options: install Ubuntu, try Ubuntu and so something else.    Thanks for the help

Comment: You can run a live session and/or install from USB but you can't install in the same, you need to connect another USB drive for that. Installing in a USB or external drive is no different from a typical install in some internal drive, some requirements and some procedure, standalone or dualboot.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just assume the USB stick will be called /dev/sdb.  You need to know what it is called.

**The install window will only show a limited amount of device options, so you need to scroll through them** by putting your mouse pointer over the device list, and scrolling the mouse wheel up and down.   In your screen-shot, you have a lot of partitions on /dev/sda, and they are taking up all the visible space in the window, so any other devices will be below those partitions.

The slider that you can grab to scroll through the window is skinny (and orange), so you might not know it's there if you're not familiar with Ubuntu.  This might lead you to believe the only options you have are those currently in front of your eyes.  You can move your mouse point over the skinny slider, and it will get fatter, so you can grab it and move it up and down.

You can figure out what your system calls your USB stick by opening **Disks**, and then plugging in the USB stick, while watching to see which new device pops up.  You can then see the device name, something like /dev/sdb, or /dev/sdc, etc..